# Изменить ссылки в группе файлов html

Tags: html, link

Потребовалось изменить текст в каталоге содержащий файлы .html, .htm. Если быть точнее изменить ссылки в документах HTML. Количество файлов .html, .htm не считал может 200, а может 300. Дерево каталогов может быть до 5-ти уровней.

Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает, как переименовать ссылки в файлах .html, .htm не вручную?

Например, заменить `http://domain.com.ua/` на `http://newdomain.ru/`

Comment: Открыть как проект в например WebStorm, ctrl+shift+r, дальше можно с просмотром или автоматом.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал.

Comment: Как минимум, пользователь сам ответил на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ из комментария:

Открыть как проект в например WebStorm, ctrl+shift+r, дальше можно с просмотром или автоматом.

Т.е. открыть любую IDE и использовать рефакторинг под названием «Переименование» ("Rename").